# Carga dinámica de lenguajes i18n

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Actualmente dispongo de un script que necesita los lenguajes en los archivos I18n pero tengo que cargarlos previamente, me gustaría saber si hay algún método para cargar solo un I18n en función del lenguaje del navegador. Estoy utilizándolo en el layout de un proyecto c#mvc.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/i18n/anypicker-i18n.js-de-at"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/i18n/anypicker-i18n.js-en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/i18n/anypicker-i18n.js-es"></script>    ...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ip-de").AnyPicker(
    {
     mode: "datetime",
     dateTimeFormat: "MMM d,yyyy",
     lang: "es"
     });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaría le des una mirada a esta implementación

[Smart internationalization for ASP.NET](https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n)

[Making I18n easy for ASP.NET devs](http://code52.org/aspnet-internationalization/)

En este se integra la internacionalización de `I18n`, veras que lo registra como módulo para que resuelva la cultura y aplique el idioma de este

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="i18n.LocalizingModule" type="i18n.LocalizingModule, i18n" />
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

al resolver la cultura puede inyectar código javascript para el idioma que detecta

Aunque hay dos partes una es como se integra asp.net mvc con la cultura y otra como lo hace javascript o jquery, más que nada para las conversiones de tipos.

[Globalization, Internationalization and Localization in ASP.NET MVC 3, JavaScript and jQuery - Part 1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Algo muy sencillo que podrías hacer es, cargar un archivo u otro archivo JavaScript dependiendo del idioma. El código quedaría algo así:

```
@{
    var localeId = "es";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/i18n/anypicker-i18n.js-@localeId"></script>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ip-de").AnyPicker(
    {
     mode: "datetime",
     dateTimeFormat: "MMM d,yyyy",
     lang: "@localeId"
     });
    }
</script>
```

En el ejemplo se estable manualmente el código de idioma en la variable `localeId`. Para obtenerlo del contexto web actual sería así (ojo, que en este caso devolvería `es-es`)

```
@{
    var localeId = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower();
}
```

Si incluyes estos métodos en tu `Global.asax` establecerás el idioma del contexto web según el idioma del navegador que está accediendo a tu aplicación

```
public static CultureInfo ResolveCulture()
{
    string[] languages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;

    if (languages == null || languages.Length == 0)
        return null;

    try
    {
        string language = languages[0].ToLowerInvariant().Trim();
        return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var culture = ResolveCulture();

    if (culture != null)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }
}
```

Todo esto lo puedes adaptar a tus necesidades, lo importante de esta solución está en establecer en idioma del hilo de ejecución actual

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Y, por supuesto, se puede refactorizar y encapsularlo en [`HtmlHelper`](http://ferquesada.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/como-crear-un-html-helper-personalizado.html), ... que evite que repitas este código varias veces o en otras aplicaciones